# how do i send a list of object from angular2 to java jersy

Tags: javascript, java, list, angular, jersey

I had this java code:

```
@Path("/SaveConfig")
@POST
@Consumes(MediaType.APPLICATION_JSON + ";charset=utf-8")
@Produces(MediaType.APPLICATION_JSON + ";charset=utf-8")
public void saveConfig(CountryGasStationConfigUi countryGasStationConfigUi) throws Exception {
```

and this angular2 code that send the data

```
var countryConfig = new CountryConfig();

this.service.saveConfig(countryConfig);
```

now the java api has changed:

```
@Path("/SaveConfig")
@POST
@Consumes(MediaType.APPLICATION_JSON + ";charset=utf-8")
@Produces(MediaType.APPLICATION_JSON + ";charset=utf-8")
public void saveConfig(List<CountryGasStationConfigUi> countryGasStationConfigUiList) throws Exception {
```

how should I send the list form angular2?

Is it simply an array?

```
var countryConfigList = [];
countryConfigList.push(new CountryConfig());

this.service.saveConfig(countryConfigList);
```

and

```
  saveConfig(countryConfigList: CountryConfig[]): any {
    console.info("sending post request");
    //some code
  }
```

Is this the way jersey would be able to parse the list?

Comment: Where's all your Http code? What problems are you facing currently? Are you getting errors? There is not enough information in your post to give you any kind of reasonable answer.